# Wordpress template_directory + path

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to figure out how to get the name of files in folder, but I can't seem to find a way to point to the right directory

```
 $location = get_template_directory_uri();
 $dir = $location.'/slider/images/';
 $files2 = scandir($dir, 1);
 print_r($files2) ;
```

Comment: Do you have permission to list files in that directory? Does the directory exists? What is `print_r` result?

Comment: @krzysiej it prints nothing. If I write the whole path : ../wp-content/themes/customDrop/slider/images/ - I get the result that I want but with get_template_directory_uri() it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in codex https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/ the function you used will return theme directory URI. So variable $location contains something like http://example.com/wp-content/themes/theme and that is something that `scandir` will not accept and understand. You have to replace this for `get_template_directory()` so $location will contains relative path like `wp-content/themes/theme`.

You just need to replace first line in your code 
  instead

```
$location = get_template_directory_uri();
```

use

```
$location = get_template_directory();
```

Answer (score 0):

another function also available in wordpress like.

```
 <?php $imgaePath = base_url() . 'your_theme_dir/slider/images' 
   echo $imagePath;
 ?>
```